# Running a main function inside another main function on a .hs file changes the behaviour IO?

Tags: haskell

I'm currently finishing my first Haskell Project and, on the final step of the work, my I/O function seems to behave strangely after I connected the different haskell files.

I have a main file (f1.hs) which loads some info of a multimedia library and saves it into variables on a new .hs file (f2.hs). I also have a "data processing and user interface" file (f3.hs), which reads those variables and, depending on what the user orders, it sorts them and displays them on screen. This f3.hs file works with menus, commanded by the valus of the keyboard input (`getLine`).

In order to make the work sequence "automatic", I made a "main" function on the f1.hs file, which creates the f2.hs file and then with the System.Cmd module, I did a `system "runhaskell f3.hs"`. This routes the user from the f1.hs file to the main function of f3.hs.

The strange thing is that, after I did that, all the `getLine` seem to appear before the last line of the function prompt.

What it should appear would be:

```
Question One.....
Answer: (cursor's place)
```

but what I get is:

```
Question One.....
(cursor's place)
Answer:
```

This only happens if I runhaskell f1.hs. If I try to `runhaskell f3.hs` directly, it works correctly (though I can't do it on the final job, as the f2.hs file needs to be created first). Am I doing something wrong with this sequence?

I'm sorry for the lack of code, but I thought that it wouldn't be any help for the understanding of the problem...

Answer (score 8):

This is typically caused by line buffering, meaning the text does not actually get printed to the console until a newline is printed. The solution is to manually flush the buffer, i.e. something like this:

```
import System.IO

main = do ...
          putStr "Answer: "
          hFlush stdout
          ...
```

Alternatively, you can disable buffering by using `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering`, though this comes at a slight performance cost, so I recommend doing the flushing manually when you need to print a partial line.

Comment: Haha, an I/O performance cost for an interactive text-based application.  Who cares?

Comment: @luqui precious milliseconds of my life! :) In seriousness, though, it's good advice to at least be aware of both `hSetBuffering` and `hFlush`, for future situations where you *do* want to take advantage of buffering settings.

Comment: @hammar thanks a lot, that worked pretty well (both solutions)! I might use the hSetBuffering stout NoBuffering as I have lots of menus and I didn't notice any performance cost, as it's a simple program... One thing I noticed, was that although this worked with printing the Strings that I put before a "getLine", I still have to press enter after I press a key on a getChar prompt...I guess I'll change it to getLine to avoid confusing the user..